# Observable isnt triggering

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have two components that should be connected via Observable().

In the first i am declaring

```
@Injectable()
export class One{
    private changeConfirmed = new Subject<boolean>();

    changeConfirmed$ = this.changeConfirmed.asObservable();
    public init$: EventEmitter<boolean>;

    registerChangeConfirmed(category:boolean){
        alert('sending')
        this.changeConfirmed.next(category);
    }

    onMsg(){
        this.registerChangeConfirmed(true);
    }
}
```

`onMsg` is event bound to template

and in the second one

```
Import { One } from './pat/to/it'
@Component({
    providers:[One]
})

export class two{
    constructor( private childClass : One ){
        this.childClass.changeConfirmed$.subscribe( x => {alert(x)})
    }
}
```

However the event does not get emitted.
But when i emit event in class two instead of class one = i include

```
this.childClass.registerChangeConfirmed(true)
```

in class two the event gets triggered. Why isn't it working when i invoke it from class one?

Comment: `EventEmitter` shouldn't be used in services. Only for `@Output()` in components and directives. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/34402436/217408

Comment: The `One` is a component or a service? Thanks!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier in fact , One is both

Answer (score 0):

Don't provide the service `One` on the component. This way each component instance will get its own `One` instance. If you provide it at a common parent (`AppComponent`) then they will get a shared instance.

Angular2 DI maintains an instance (singleton) per provider.

Comment: u mean not adding providers:[ One ] to class Two component but to their parent? If so , this does not solve problem ( but might be usefull , thanks for that )

Comment: Did you check `onMsg()` actually gets called? Can you please add the code that shows how you're doing it?

Comment: Where do you include `this.childClass.registerChangeConfirmed(true)`. It's hard to see what's going on when only seeing fragments but not how they are actually related.